# I'm trying to save my restaurant data( photos, names, prices) into Firebase Real Time Database & retrieve it from there not data file in React Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-hooks, react-context

Here is my code to retrieve data from normal data using Flat List:

```
const renderCategory =()=>{
   return(
    <View style={{
      height:80,
        marginTop:6
    }}>
    <FlatList 
    horizontal
    contentContainerStyle={{
       // marginLeft:SIZES.base,
        paddingHorizontal:SIZES.base,
        
    }}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    data={dummyData?.restaurantMenu}
    keyExtractor={item=>`${item.id}`}
    renderItem={({item,index})=>{
        return(
            <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
                height:60,
                width:80,
                marginHorizontal:4,
                marginTop:SIZES.base,
                justifyContent:'center',
                alignItems:'center',
                borderRadius:SIZES.radius,
                borderWidth:1,
                borderColor: select ===  index ? COLORS.gray2 : COLORS.gray2,
                //backgroundColor: select === index ? COLORS.primary : null
               
            }}
            onPress={()=>  navigation.navigate('Menu',{item})}
            >
                  <Image 
                source={item.icon}
                resizeMode='contain'
                style={{
                    height:40,
                    width:40,
                    tintColor: select === index ? COLORS.gray3 : COLORS.gray
                }}
                />
                <Text
                style={{
                    ...FONTS.h3,
                    color: select === index ? COLORS.gray3 : COLORS.gray,
                    fontFamily:'Courgette-Regular'
                    
                }}
                >{item.name}</Text>
              
                

            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }}
    
    />
    </View>
)
```

Here is my dummy data file:

```
export const restaurantMenu = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Western",
        foodType:'Western Food',
        rating: 4.8,
        categories: [1],
        icon: icons.western,
        photo: images.background_1,
        price: 20.00,
        menu:[
        {
           id: 1,
            name: "Chicken Fajita",
            photo: images.Chicken_Fajita,
            description: "Grilled Chicken Breast, Onion, Bell Pepper, Fajita Sauce",
            price: 20.00,
            rating:3,
            reviews:89,

        },
        {
           id: 2,
            name: "Cordon Bleu",
            photo: images.Cordon_Bleu,
            description: "Panne Fried Chicken Breast Stuffed with Mozzarella Cheese, 
            Mushroom",
            price: 21.00,
            rating:4,
            reviews:90,

    
        },
      ],

 {
    id: 2,
    name: "Burgers",
    rating: 4.5,
    categories: [2],
    icon: icons.burger,
    photo: images.background_2,
    price: 10.00,
    menu:[
        {
           id: 3,
            name: "Beef Burger",
            photo: images.Beef_Burger,
            description: "Fresh Beef Patty, Lettuce, Mayonnaise Topped with Cheddar Cheese",
            price: 15.00,
            rating:3,
            reviews:89,

        },
        {
           id: 4,
            name: "Chicken Burger",
            photo: images.Chicken_Burger,
            description: "Fresh Chicken Burger Patty, Lettuce, Garlic Sauce, Cocktail Sauce,",
            price: 15.00,
            rating:3,
            reviews:89,
        },
  ]
```

This code is my app data I wanna save it into firebase and retrieve it from there instead of using normal JS file. I was trying to do so but unfortunately I couldn't. So how I can use firebase real time database and save my app data there and retrieve it from there

Comment: "I was trying to do so but unfortunately I couldn't" is really hard to help with, and Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger. --- If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Answer (score 0):

I will provide some links to the official docs

[Install & Init Real Time DB](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start)

[Read and Write data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data)

Here is the default example for getting real time updates of your data

```
import { getDatabase, ref, onValue} from "firebase/database";

const db = getDatabase();
const starCountRef = ref(db, 'posts/' + postId + '/starCount');
onValue(starCountRef, (snapshot) => {
  const data = snapshot.val();
  updateStarCount(postElement, data);
});
```

Comment: my problem now is how to implement the connection in the code how to replace the data in flat List what i can do and how .if you look at my using flat list how to implement to firebase